# How to call many different Winforms having similar parameter in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've following Winforms.

`frmBase`
`frmChild1`, `frmChild2`.....,`frmChild20`

Totally 21 Forms. From `frmBase`, I'll call all other forms on Button click based on condition. All are having 3 set of parameters. Eg:

```
frmChild1 objForm = new frmChild1();
objForm.strName = txtName.Text1;
objForm.strAddr = txtAddress.Text2;
objForm.strCity = txtCity.Text2;
objForm.ShowDialog();
```

If I call all forms like this, I've huge amount of coding. Since only Form name is changing, is there anyother simple way to call all 20 forms from Base form button click.

Comment: Make a list of the required form types and instantiate them via a loop. But with ShowDialog you can only show one at a time anyway.

Comment: You can't use ShowDialog for more than one form at the time anyway... What's the point of instantiating all forms at once?

Comment: @ZoharPeled , Not all forms at once. I've a dropdown above the button. In that dropdown, I'll select one form after filling up the textboxes and when I click the button, corresponding form should open.

Comment: @Lennart, I know with ShowDialog I can only show one at a time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code.

**Solution 1:**

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class ObjectFinder
{
    private static object CreateObjectInstance(string objectName)
    {
        // Creates and returns an instance of any object in the assembly by its type name.
        object obj = null;
        try {
            if (objectName.LastIndexOf(".") == -1) {
                //Appends the root namespace if not specified.
                objectName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.GetName.Name, objectName);
            }
            obj = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.CreateInstance(objectName);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            obj = null;
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public static Form CreateForm(Form objForm, string strName, string strAddr, string strCity)
    {
        // Return the instance of the form by specifying its name.
        var objChild = (objForm)CreateObjectInstance(objForm.Name);
        objChild.strName = txtName.Text1;
        objChild.strAddr = txtAddress.Text2;
        objChild.strCity = txtCity.Text2;
        return objChild;
    }
}
```

You could call this static function to create child form as below

```
objForm = ObjectFinder.CreateForm(frmChild1, strName, strAddr, strCity);
objForm.ShowDialog();
```

**Solution 2:**

or, Simply create extension method of `Form` object as below.

```
public static Form CreateForm(this Form objForm, string strName, string strAddr, string strCity)
{
    // Return the instance of the form by specifying its name.
    var objChild = (objForm)CreateObjectInstance(objForm.Name);
    objChild.strName = txtName.Text1;
    objChild.strAddr = txtAddress.Text2;
    objChild.strCity = txtCity.Text2;
    return objChild;
}
```

and, call this extension method as below

```
objForm = frmChild1.CreateForm(strName, strAddr, strCity);
objForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

The forms should implement a common interface (that you define), then you can iterate through the list of Interfaces (regardless of what implementation each form has for the interface. and do the stuff you want. For example something like this:

```
public interface IMyForm
{
    string strName { get; set; }
    string strAddress {get; set; }
    string strCity { get; set; }
    void ShowDialog();
}
```

then if all of your forms implement that interface your main form can keep a list of all its child forms in a list of IMyForm and just loop through and assign/show all the things.

If all the forms have the same control you could also write a base `Form` and inherit the other forms from that form and maintain the same kind of list.
If the forms just differ in text in the title, you should write 1 form that has the controls all your form instances will need and just pass different form titles into its creation.

Comment: `void ShowDialog();` can be skipped if all the elements inherit from `Form` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on what is your need but you should consider adding all the forms in a `List<Form>` creating a method or work on the constructor.

The advantage could be that you can call them with an `enumerator` or a `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Skintkingle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45324543/3094533), 
You can add a `Dictionary<object, Func<IMyForm>>` to your main form, that will hold the selected item of the dropdown as it's key, and the constructor of the form as it's value:

```
private Dictionary<object, Func<IMyForm>> _SubForms = new Dictionary<object, Func<IMyForm>>()
{
    {"Form1", () => {return new Form1();}},
    {"Form2", () => {return new Form2();}
    //....
};
```

And then, in your button click, all you need to do is this:

```
var selectedItem = MyDropDown.SelectedItem;
if(_SubForms.ContainsKey(selectedItem)
{
    var form = _SubForms[selectedItem]();
    form.strName = txtName.Text1;
    form.strAddr = txtAddress.Text2;
    form.strCity = txtCity.Text2;
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```